# Change Flutter Drawer Background Color

Tags: navigation-drawer, flutter, drawer

How can I change the background color of a flutter nav drawer?
There doesn't seem to be a color or background-color property.

Comment: Drawer documentation lists BackgroundColor property, but it doesn't seem to exist. Strange.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you build your `ListView` in the `child` property of your `Drawer`, you can wrap your different sections of the `Drawer` inside a `Container` and use the `color` property of the `Container`.

[image]

```
drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(child: new DrawerHeader(child: new CircleAvatar()),color: Colors.tealAccent,),
            new Container (
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: new Column(
                children: new List.generate(4, (int index){
                  return new ListTile(
                    leading: new Icon(Icons.info),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

A better alternative if you already have a consistent coloring design in your mind, is to define your `ThemeData` under the theme property of the root of your app, the `DrawerHeader` and the body will follow your `canvasColor`, so you need to override the value of one of them to change the color:

[image]

```
return new MaterialApp(
....
theme: new ThemeData(
       canvasColor: Colors.redAccent,

       ....),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice about `ThemeData`. IMHO, using consistent color scheme is a way to go here.

Answer (score 51):

Best way to wrap `Drawer` with `Theme`,

For example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        //other scaffold items
        drawer: Theme(
           data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                 canvasColor: Colors.blue, //This will change the drawer background to blue.
                 //other styles
              ),
              child: Drawer(
                 child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       //drawer stuffs
                    ],
                 ),
             ),
        );
  }
```

Comment: Only this works for transparent background

Comment: this doesn’t work  to me, i dont now why, maybe because i have the drawer in a component

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way would probably be to just wrap the `ListView` inside a `Container` and specify its color like following:

```
drawer: Drawer(
  child: Container(color: Colors.red,
    child: new ListView(
      ...
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 9):

For changing Drawer header color, you can use below code :

---

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
  accountName: Text("Ashish Rawat"),
  accountEmail: Text("ashishrawat2911@gmail.com"),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color(0xFF00897b),
  ),
  currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctxt).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
        ? const Color(0xFF00897b)
        : Colors.white,
    child: Text(
      "A",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just use this code;

```
drawer: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          //child: Your widget,
          color: Colors.red,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 3):

**PLAIN BACKGROUND**

Just set your desired theme color using ***primarySwatch*: Colors.brown** property in ***ThemeData***

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown, // Your app THEME-COLOR
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}
```

**GRADIENT BACKGROUND**
Add the ***gradient*** property to ***AppBar***.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("profyl.org",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    const Color(0xFF3366FF),
                    const Color(0xFF00CCFF),
                  ],
                  begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                  end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                  stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                  tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: HomeListPage(),
        drawer: DrawerPage());
  }
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Try This.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          children: [

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This will help**

```
 drawer: Drawer(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFF56ccf2),
            ),
            accountName: Text("User Name Goes"),
            accountEmail: Text("emailaddress@gmail.com"),
            currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor:
              Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                  ? Color(0xFF56ccf2)
                  : Colors.white,
              child: Text("TK",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50,
                  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,),),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Home',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18,
                )),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 0, 5),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right,
              color: Colors.white,),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: As this is some pretty extensive code, you should probably add a little bit of explanation or related documents such as documentation.

Comment: @FabianBettag Okay. I will do so next time I make an attempt to answer a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(color:Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor),
    )],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap whatever you have in your drawer with a container wrapped with expanded widget. Thus you can change the color of the container there. Something like this will work.

```
Drawer(
    child: Expanded(
      child: Container(
       color: Colors.red,
       child: Text('Tabs'),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DrawerThemeData:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
   drawerTheme: const DrawerThemeData(
     backgroundColor: Color(0xff24191b),
   ),
  ),
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

> In drawer wrap Container on ListView or ListTile Data

```
Container(
  color: Colors.indigo,
  child: ListView.builder(....))
```

[image]