# Which ThemeData property changes Drawer background color?

Tags: flutter, widget, themes, background-color, drawer

In other words, how to change `Drawer` default background color using `ThemeData` while setting light / dark themes for `MaterialApp` widget.

I have searched for something like `drawerTheme` but `ThemeData` [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html) does not have such property. Changing `backgroundColor` etc doesn't work either. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951907/change-flutter-drawer-background-color) topic suggests wrapping `Drawer` with `Theme` and use `canvasColor` which thankfully works, but I'm searching for clean solution to achieve this using `ThemeData` without need for wrapping every single `Drawer` in my application.

[image: This is Drawer with pitch black background color]

Answer (score 0):

I'm blind. The answer is in the very thread I've linked. The solution to the problem is changing `canvasColor` property of `ThemeData`.